# confusion with some objective-c protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols, nsobject

I downloaded the source code for an application called adium, because I wanted to learn cocoa better by scrutinizing other people's code, but there is something very confusing to me in this interface:

```
@interface AIAdium : NSObject <AIAdium, SUVersionComparison> {
@private
IBOutlet    NSObject <AIMenuController>         *menuController;
IBOutlet    NSObject <AIInterfaceController>        *interfaceController;
IBOutlet    SUUpdater                                   *updater;

NSObject <AIAccountController>                  *accountController;
NSObject <AIChatController>                     *chatController;
NSObject <AIContactController>                  *contactController;
NSObject <AIContentController>                  *contentController;...
```

It goes on like this.  What I don't understand is how NSObjects are conforming to protocols like AIAccountController. I thought you had to implement the methods defined in the interface of a protocol to conform to it, but how could NSObject be doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what those lines mean. Example:

```
NSObject <AIAccountController> *accountController;
```

What this means is that the `accountController` ivar is a pointer to any `NSObject` derived class that also conforms to the `AIAccountController` protocol.

Since `NSObject` is the root class of most other classes, this basically means any custom class that conforms to the protocol can be assigned to the ivar.

Nothing about the line has any bearing on `NSObject` itself.

What the author of this code should have used was:

```
id<AIAccountController> accountController;
```

Comment: Most likely the author was using NSObject for retain, release or respondsToSelector:. But in that case you can just conform to the NSObject protocol.

Comment: @Chuck You can achieve that (and I see this pattern a lot) by having your custom protocol (in this case `AIAccountController`) 'inherit' from `NSObject`, like this: `@protocol AIAccountController <NSObject>`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had no idea ivars could be written like this.

Comment: @NicolasMiari That's what I do. All of my protocols extend the `NSObject` protocol.